# Echo file url as image

Tags: php, image, echo

I have this line of code to echo an image (thumb)

```
printf('<img src="./uploads/designments/%s/thumbs/80x80">',$item['designment_id']);
```

On the page it will show the broken image icon. and if I look in the elements I see the following path: `/uploads/designments/71/thumbs/80x80"`

If I look in the ftp to the corresponding file name I see here the path is:
 `/uploads/designments/71/thumbs/80x80/calculator_wheat_0.jpg`

So what do I have to add to my code to get the corresponding filename in the URL?

Comment: You did't give `calculator_wheat_0.jpg` to your `printf` function..

Comment: I know but it isn't only the calculator_wheat_0.jpg image. I need to get the right image with the right 'designment' Like I did with the $item['designment_id'] for the right designment

Comment: Is your image name stored somewhere??

Comment: Is there a way how I can open it the next map (path) if thats possible it will the right image with the right designment.

Comment: Make something like this: `printf('<img src="./uploads/designments/%s/thumbs/80x80%s">',$item['designment_id'], $item['image_name']);`

Comment: I get the following error: severity: NOTICE message: undefined index: IMAGE_NAME filename:template/designerid_view.php

Answer (score -1):

You closed off the image tag a little too early. Try:
printf('< img src="./uploads/designments/%s/thumbs/80x80/',$item['designment_id'],'">');

Comment: it will the right image with the right designment.
@Frayne Konok Comment `printf('<img src="./uploads/designments/%s/thumbs/80x80/%s">',$item['designment_id'], $item['image_name']);` will work

Comment: I get the following error:  severity: NOTICE   message: undefined index: IMAGE_NAME  filename:template/designerid_view.php

Comment: I think we have to replace image_name with something else so it will put the file name in the url.